# Get Facebook's users' application list

Tags: facebook

I want to ask a question:

When a Facebook user use my apps, can I retrieve their application list?

I have a scenario that will require this:

- People play my game.
- If they have already play another game of mine, then they will have a bonus gift.

So I need to know if they've already used that another app or not. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "me/accounts" for see all app of current user
(example : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts )

Comment: With this, I can only get apps that I own, not apps that I've used. :)
Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> So I need to know if they've already used that another app or not.

Then you’ll have to save the user ids of people playing your games into your own database.